# Excel 2003 VBA - kernel32 functions - and other libs

Tags: excel, vba, windows-xp, excel-2003

I've been programming in VBA for Excel 2003 for some years now, and only recently I've been introduced to:

```
Declare Sub AAAA Lib "kernel32" Alias "AAAA"
```

by an [answer here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876300/timed-alarm-in-excel-vba/8510092#8510092).

What I've been unable to find is (no googlefu could help me):

- What are all the functions available in "**kernel32**"?
- What are the other available (free) **LIBS**?
- Can I make my own?

I just need some pointers, ideas and/or tutorial links to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Try http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp, http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/apilist.php and http://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/VFD153/LA416011411.htm for starters. Google is very useful here.

Comment: @JP.: IMHO: your comment is worth an answer (provided you elaborate it a little more) as it answers most part of the questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking at are **Windows API declarations**.

Several popular examples include:

- [Declaring API functions in 64 bit Office](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp)
- [API List](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/apilist.php)
- [Windows APIs](http://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/VFD153/LA416011411.htm)

As far your specific questions:

> What are all the functions available in "kernel32"

A DLL viewer such as [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) or [ApiViewer](http://www.activevb.de/rubriken/apiviewer/index-apiviewereng.html) may be useful here.

> What are the other available (free) LIBS

See the links I posted, although I imagine there are dozens or hundreds more proprietary DLLs that we'll never find.

> Can I make my own?

Yes, but I only have experience creating ActiveX DLLs so I can't speak to that. I did find one example, however: [What is a DLL?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815065)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete(I think) list. Hope this helps?

http://eric.aling.tripod.com/PB/kernel.htm

Sid